# concatenation in laravel controller goes wrong

Tags: laravel-5

```
$data = <div class="">
    <h3><a class="text-dark" href=" url("/notice_details/'.$n->id.'")">'.$n->title.'</a>**</h3>

    <p class="text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar m-r-5"></i>Posted on :'.$n->date.'</p>

    <p class="font-13 text-muted m-b-0">
         '.$string.'
    </p>
</div>
```

this is the code in my controller(laravel project 5.5) want to generate the url in view like `localhost/learning/notice_details/1` in my project `url()` returns localhost/learning but i m unable to genrate the right href link may something wrong with concatenation or .... ??

Comment: write like `href="/notice_details/'.$n->id.'"`

Answer (score 0):

Never use HTML in yours' controllers.
- In your learning controller add index function before you to go to view, make.

```
public function index(){
$n = Notice::all();
$string = "your string";
return view('notice_datails', compact('n', 'string'));
}
```

And your html

```
@foreach($n as $notice)
<div class="">
  <h3>
   <a class="text-dark" href="{{url("/notice_details/$notice->id")}} "> {{$notice->title}} </a>
  </h3>

  <p class="text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar m-r-5"></i>Posted on : {{$notice->date}}</p>

   <p class="font-13 text-muted m-b-0">
     {{$string}}
   </p>
</div>  
@endforeach
```